# Move files/resources to the bin folder in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn

I have a `C#` console app in VS 2017 and inside this I have a folder called `libs`. This contains some `dlls` that I need to be copied to the bin folder upon compilation of the project.

VS copies this to `/bin/libs/` at the moment. Is there a way to configure it to put these files directly into `/bin/` instead?

The dlls are set to `Build Action: None` and `Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always`

Comment: Are these dlls referenced to by the program in the regular way (add reference) or is there a different dependency?

Comment: No, they are not referenced assemblies. They are basically just copied to the bin folder as a dependency. These are from the [sevenzipsharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipSharp/) library.

Comment: If you reference sevenzipsharp as a nuget package all required dlls should be copied automatically to the bin folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to do this is to use a Post-Build event (under Project -> Properties -> Build Events) to [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) the files. That's as about 'builtin' as you are going to get.

e.g.

```
xcopy /y /r $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) $(ProjectDir)..\DestFolder\$(TargetFileName)
```

[Common Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/ide/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties)